# Anchoring multiple objects in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, anchor-point, formatting

I have several images anchored in my text flow, and I'd like to annotate these images with some arrows. The problem is that the drawing tools (line, pencil, etc) not anchor to the image. So when the text changes, the image moves up or down and the arrows remain in place.

How can I anchor these arrows to the image, so they move as well?

[image: Problem]

Comment: So you're looking to have 2 objects (image+arrow) anchored to the same paragraph?

Comment: I suppose. But I had trouble enabling anchors for these lines in the first place, so I doubt they are considered to be full objects...

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to have 2 objects (image+arrow) anchored to the same paragraph, then you can group the image and arrow, then anchor this group to your paragraph. When anchored, a group flows like a single object.

Comment: Ah, yes that might work as well. I already had the image anchored and it was impossible to select both objects at the same time. But removing the anchor, grouping and anchoring again works.

Comment: Great. If you feel this answers your question try clicking the _check_ icon and the _up_ arrow next to my answer above. Thanks!

Comment: I know, but I am still on a timer. Will accept in 7 more minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

During the time before I could accept the answer I accidentally discovered another method that does not require ungrouping. By cutting the line and pasting it inline directly behind the image, then applying a custom anchor position to it and dragging it into place. It also flows up and down with the text.

I suppose it is a little less foolproof, because theoretically one could type between the two anchors, but it is slightly faster.

Comment: yes you can anchor separately if that works better for you, it can get more tricky to control but it might work